# My first prolog tiny program doesn't work

Tags: prolog

I've thrown a glance at Prolog, and this is my first little try at writing it: it directly bugs at my first queries. (in the example below i asked for word('test').)

I meant to state:

- word/1
- alias/2
- alias is commutative
- if a variable is an alias of another then it is a word
- A, C, and D are word
- B is an alias of A.

this is the knowledge base when I do a listing. in SWI-Prolog console.

```
?- listing.
word(A) :-
    alias(A, B).
word('A').
word('C').
word('D').

alias(A, B) :-
        alias(B, A).
alias('A', 'B').

Yes
3 ?- word('test').
ERROR: Out of local stack
Exception: (59,743) alias(_L147, test) ?
```

Any clue what's going wrong with my knwoledge base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alias(A, B) :-
        alias(B, A).
alias('A', 'B').
```

this is an infinite loop.
for example, if you call `alias(2,4)` then the trace would be something like:

```
alias(2,4)
alias(4,2)
alias(2,4)
alias(4,2)
alias(2,4)
alias(4,2)
alias(2,4)
alias(4,2)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a left recursively issue.
Look here at page 133: http://books.google.com/books?id=w-XjuvpOrjMC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=prolog+commutativity&source=bl&ots=4Xz2WMBUNt&sig=pj1blZvMvHXoQPBHEPBNnVo2f6E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xpAcT_ieMIj00gGdhq3oCw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=prolog%20commutativity&f=false

Comment: really nice of you. exactly what i needed.